# Chrome WebRTC echo cancellation and external audio sources

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, aec, echo-cancellation

I'm building a video conferencing app using Electron (version 10, Chrome v75) and WebRTC. The app has multiple windows, and in each window, I have a separate RTCPeerConnection with a different app user. The problem is that if I don't use headphones, there is a strong echo that makes the app almost unusable.

I tried setting all sorts of `getUserMedia` options like `echoCancellation: true` or `googEchoCancellation: true`, `echoCancellationType: "browser"/"system"`, but none of them managed to cancel out the echo from various sound sources.

This problem appears only on Mac and Linux, while Windows suppresses the echo quite efficiently.

I found this Chromium issue that describes a similar problem [in more detail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1261).

Also, when I try out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/n7bmkjnf/) on Chrome + Mac or Linux (although Chrome is not perfect for this very case, find more details [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-of-the-week-audio-constraints/)), I see no effects of echo cancellation and the echo is still there. However, the same thing on Chrome + Windows or Firefox + any OS works perfectly.

Can it really be that AEC (echo cancellation) within Chrome does not take into account all sound sources, and does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? It's interesting how different firefox/chrome are!

Answer (score 0):

add video.volume = 0 to access camera and when you start recording. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm answering your question but: Chrome/Firefox do not take into account all sound sources. Chrome handles only RTCPeerConnection audio tracks. And I *think* not between tabs.

Perhaps I'm misreading your question though, because you seem to think Windows works fine. But maybe Chrome is using some native Windows echo cancellation feature?

Related links:

- https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/1243
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215049
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687574
- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/more-native-echo-cancellation/